# npm formidable install - getting errror

Tags: javascript, npm

trying to install formidable JS library but having some install trouble, 
it seems like  https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable is down, and using isup.me, the registry site seems to be down completely = can anyone else confirm this as the problem or is it something that I am doing wrong on my side?

THanks! here is the error log from console

```
  ^C[~/Documents/Projects/moocs/starup engnineering/nodetutorial]$npm install formidable
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/formidable
    npm ERR! Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR!     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
    npm ERR!     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19)
    npm ERR!  { [Error: connect ECONNREFUSED]
    npm ERR!   code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    npm ERR!   errno: 'ECONNREFUSED',
    npm ERR!   syscall: 'connect' }
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
    npm ERR! 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

    npm ERR! System Darwin 12.4.0
    npm ERR! command "/usr/local/Cellar/node/0.10.3/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "formidable"
    npm ERR! cwd /Users/TheGiantSpider/Documents/Projects/moocs/starup engnineering/nodetutorial
    npm ERR! node -v v0.10.3
    npm ERR! npm -v 1.2.17
    npm ERR! syscall connect
    npm ERR! code ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! errno ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! stack Error: connect ECONNREFUSED
    npm ERR! stack     at errnoException (net.js:878:11)
    npm ERR! stack     at Object.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (net.js:869:19)
    npm ERR! 
    npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
    npm ERR!     /Users/TheGiantSpider/Documents/Projects/moocs/starup engnineering/nodetutorial/npm-debug.log
    npm ERR! not ok code 0
```

Comment: What's your npm version?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
npm config set registry="http://registry.npmjs.org/"
```

It worked for me.